# Getting using multiple jquery .get() doesn't return the data in sequence?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Like the title says, I'm using multiple url's to get my data from and I'm using the jquery .get() method. For example:

```
var m=0;
$.get(url1).done(function(data) 
{
    list[m] = data;
    m++;
}
$.get(url2).done(function(data) 
{
    list[m] = data;
    m++;
}
$.get(url3).done(function(data) 
{
    list[m] = data;
    m++;
}
$.get(url4).done(function(data) 
{
    list[m] = data;
    m++;
}
```

I have four url's there and I'm putting the data into a array `list[]`. I will need the data to be in sequence, meaning `list[1]` comes from url1, `list[2]` from url2 and so on.

But the problem is, it's not always in sequence. Sometimes I get data like `list[1]` from url4 or `list[2]` from url1. Seems like using multiple `.get()` functions does not always return the data in sequence. Do you guys know how to get the data return in sequence using the .get() function?

Comment: You would have to nest the `$.get()`s and remember that the `list` would only be available in your last success function.

Comment: You need to actually chain them together so that on success of the first one, the success function calls the next one, then the success of that calls the next one and so on. I would also look into using promises so that you can build up an array of promises and then use .then to execute sequentially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to chain them all together so the success of one get fires off the next get. You could setup another function to be called as the callback when the last get completes. Something like this (haven't tested it)

```
var m=0;
$.get(url1).done(function (data) {
    list[m] = data;
    m++;

    $.get(url2).done(function (data) {
        list[m] = data;
        m++;

        $.get(url3).done(function (data) {
            list[m] = data;
            m++;

            $.get(url4).done(function (data) {
                list[m] = data;
                m++;
                alldone(data);
            });
        });
    });
});

function allDone(data) {
    //do this when last one completes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is asynchronous, and the responses can come in a different order than the order you sent the requests.

One solution is to make `m` a closure variable that's set at the time you send the request, so you can then fill in the correct list element:

```
$.each([url1, url2, url3, url4], function(m, url) {
    $.get(url).done(function(data) {
        list[m] = data;
    });
});
```